# Calculate perimeter of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array, mathematical-morphology

I want to calculate the perimeter of a given numpy array structure. With perimeter i mean the exact perimeter of the structure in the numpy array. The structure could include holes.

My current aproach is something like this:

```
import numpy   
a = numpy.zeros((6,6), dtype=numpy.int)
a[1:5, 1:5] = 1;a[3,3] = 0
# Way 1
s = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2,1)
c = ndimage.binary_dilation(a,s).astype(a.dtype)
b = c - a  
numpy.sum(b) # The result, however the hole is calculated as 1, although there are 4 edges

# Way 2
b = ndimage.distance_transform_cdt(a == 0,metric='taxicab') == 1 
b = b.astype(int)
numpy.sum(b) # same as above
```

[image]

As you can see it displays all adjacent cells, however the sum of them doesn't equal the perimeter of the patch. The hole in the example array is calculated as 1 although it correctly has 4 edges. There are similar issues with greater holes of different shapes.

I have asked similar questions in the past, but all provided solutions which somehow didn't resolve in the correct output values in the end.
Someone has an idea how to accomplish this? 
No other packages than numpy, scipy and the base packages please.

Comment: What value do you expect in this example?

Comment: An integer value. In the above test data set the final value should be 20, because there are 20 edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean, in the image, the total number of length-1 edges that separate blue-colored from red-colored tiles?  In the picture above this number would be 28.  In the example you give in code (which is slightly different, not having the 4 corners differ from the rest of the border tiles) it would be 20.

If that's what you want to compute, you can do something like:

`numpy.sum(a[:,1:] != a[:,:-1]) + numpy.sum(a[1:,:] != a[:-1,:])`

Comment: the image is the resulting array (b) plotted.

Comment: yeah, works! I am chosing your solution, because it is considerable smaller and faster

Answer (score 6):

Count the number of edges in the interior and at the edges (assumes binary image):

```
n_interior = abs(diff(a, axis=0)).sum() + abs(diff(a, axis=1)).sum()
n_boundary = a[0,:].sum() + a[:,0].sum() + a[-1,:].sum() + a[:,-1].sum()
perimeter = n_interior + n_boundary
```

You can leave out n_boundary if the image is properly zero padded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my answer because the existing ones have the same problem:
If a pixel is both different to the one above and the one to the left it's counted twice if you do:

```py
numpy.sum(a[:,1:] != a[:,:-1]) + numpy.sum(a[1:,:] != a[:-1,:])
```

This is fixed by using an elementwise or before doing the summation:

```py
np.logical_or(
    (a[:,1:] != a[:,:-1])[1:,:], 
    (a[1:,:] != a[:-1,:])[:,1:]).sum()
```