# Calculate number of equal neighbouring cells within a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, mathematical-morphology

I have 2d binary `numpy` `arrays` of varying size, which contain certain patterns. 
Just like this:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.zeros((6,6), dtype=numpy.int)
a[1,2] = a[1,3] = 1
a[4,4] = a[5,4] = a[4,3] = 1
```

Here the "image" contains two patches one with 2 and one with 3 *connected* cells.

```
print a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

I want to know how often a non-zero cell borders another non-zero cell ( **neighbours defined as rook's case**, so the cells to the left, right, below and above each cell) including their pseudo-replication (so vice-versa).

A previous [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443246/calculate-perimeter-of-numpy-array) for inner boundaries returns wrong values (5) as it was intended to calculate outer boundaries.

```
numpy.abs(numpy.diff(a, axis=1)).sum()
```

So for the above test array, the correct total result would be **6** (The upper patch has two internal borders, the lower four ).

Grateful for any tips!

EDIT:

- Mistake: The lower obviously has 4 internal edges (neighbouring cells with the same value)
- Explained the desired neighbourhood a bit more

Comment: What does "neighbours defined as rook's case" mean?

Comment: Why the lower is six?

Comment: Well the obvious solution would be to just double-loop over the indices and count.

Comment: I need to check if the neighbours to the left, right, below and above each cell (rook) are equal to the center cell. @HYRY : Mistake, sorry. The lower one has 4 internal borders (cells neighbouring cells with same value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the result is 8 if it's 8-connected neighborhood. Here is the code:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.zeros((6,6), dtype=numpy.int)
a[1,2] = a[1,3] = 1
a[4,4] = a[5,4] = a[4,3] = 1

from scipy.ndimage import convolve

kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
kernel[1, 1] = 0
b = convolve(a, kernel, mode="constant")
b[a != 0].sum()
```

but you said rook's case.

**edit**

Here is the code for 4-connected neighborhood:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=np.int)
a[1,2] = a[1,3] = 1
a[4,4] = a[5,4] = a[4,3] = 1

from scipy import ndimage
kernel = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2, 1)
kernel[1, 1] = 0

b = convolve(a, kernel, mode="constant")
b[a != 0].sum()
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I want to know a simple 4x4 neighboorhood (so no diagonal connections, eg. left,right,above, below).  I edited my question above as the correct answer is indeed **6** and not *8* (the total number of equal neighbors in the lower half is 4)

Comment: I tried to adapt your example, but it doesn't seem to be that easy...         ```s = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2,2)
s[0,0] = s[0,2] = s[2,0] = s[2,2] = 0 
b = ndimage.convolve(a, s, mode="constant")
b[a != 0].sum()  # equals 11 ```

Comment: Whop, that does the trick. Forgot to replace the center cell... Thanks!