# How to get a value in a nested list that is smaller than the ones around it

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically I have to find the smallest number in a nested list as compared to the numbers around it. This would be called a 'sink' and the function returns True if it is a sink and False if it isn't. For example, if the nested list is

```
[[1, 2, 1],
 [4, 6, 5],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

then the number at [0,2], (1), should be true as all the values adjacent to it are smaller than 1 but the number at [2, 0], (7), shouldn't be true as it is greater than some of the values around it.

I tried to use slicing to get the numbers beside it but I don't know how to slice it to get the number diagonal from the sink or above or below. 
This is some of the code that I tried to do:

```
for x in elevation_map:
    for xs in x:
        if elevation_map[cell[0]][cell[1]] < xs[cell[0]]:
            return True
return False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please add the full expected output for that input. You can [edit] the question. I guess it would be `[[True, False, True], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]`. See [ask] and [mre] if you want more advice.

Comment: This seems like something NumPy would be good at.

Comment: What are you counting as "adjacent" - the four orthogonal directions, or eight directions including diagonals?

Comment: This might be useful? [Calculate number of equal neighbouring cells within a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36367531/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your list of lists to a `numpy` array, iterate the indices, and use two-dimensional slicing to get the sub-matrix and check whether the value at the current position is the minimal value.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from itertools import product
>>> m = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
...               [4, 6, 5],
...               [7, 8, 9]])
...
>>> [(r, c, m[r,c]) for r,c in product(*map(range, m.shape))
...                 if m[r,c] == m[max(0,r-1):r+2,max(0,c-1):c+2].min()]
...       
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1)]
```

(The `max(0, ...)` is so that the lower bound `0-1` does not refer to the last element in the array; if the upper bound is higher then the size of the array, that's not a problem.)

Note: This will also identify a point as a "sink" if one of it's neighbors has *the same* value; not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but we haven't learned that and therefore I can't use it but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

> don't know how to slice it to get the number diagonal from the sink
>   or above or below.

Your question shows an indexing scheme of `[row,col]`.

Diagonals:

```
[row-1,col-1], [row-1,col+1], [row+1,col-1], [row+1,col+1]
```

left, right, up down:

```
[row,col-1],[row,col+1],[row-1,col],[row+1,col]
```

---

`[row-1,col-1]`  `[row-1, col ]`  `[row-1,col+1]`
`[ row ,col-1]` **`[ row , col ]`**  `[ row ,col+1]`
`[row+1,col-1]`  `[row+1, col ]`  `[row+1,col+1]`

When calculating the indices you will need to include checks to see if you are at the edge of the *2-d* structure. If you are at the left edge then `col-1` will rap around to the last item in that row and if you are at the top edge then `row-1` will rap around to the last item in that column. You also might want to check for the right and bottom edge - there won't be any *cells* at `col+1` or `row+1`.

Comment: That `row-1` and `col-1` part could go wrong if `row` or `col` is `0`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a value a sink if it is the minimum of the surrounding 3x3 grid, i.e. you don't require that it is strictly smaller than any other value around it, then you can use [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) in order to create a window that checks the 3x3 neighbors. In order to work at the edges of the matrix, the original array can be padded with `np.inf` (since `min` is later used):

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array(
[[1, 2, 1],
 [4, 6, 5],
 [7, 8, 9]])

padded = np.pad(matrix.astype(float), 1, constant_values=np.inf)
window = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
    padded,
    padded.shape + (3, 3),
    padded.strides * 2)[:-2, :-2]

result = matrix == window.min(axis=(-2, -1))
```

Which gives the following result:

```
[[ True False  True]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]]
```